# Can't get iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob permission in Google cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase app with a Google Cloud Function. In the cloud function, I'm trying to sign a blob:

```
  const [url] = await fbadmin.storage().bucket(bucket).file(filename).getSignedUrl(options)
```

This uses the Firebase Admin storage SDK. The cloud function should be running as my default cloud function service account, which I believe is `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` (this is a 1st gen cloud function). I get this error:

```
 Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
```

The resource (a Google Storage file, `gs://PROJECT_ID.appspot.com/Users/BiHGBDRAs/Projects/Project1/files/out.mp4`) does exist.

I'm not an expert on Google Cloud IAM. In the console, I granted the principal `PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` access to the service account of the same name (it's called "App Engine Default Service Account"), and added the Service Account Token Creator role which includes the `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob` permission.

It still doesn't work. Running `gcloud projects get-iam-policy PROJECT_ID` I do not see that new role. The only service account with that role is `firebase-adminsdk-z3a69@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. I originally thought that would work, since my cloud function is using the firebase admin SDK.

Any hints? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the console didn't work, but doing it in the terminal with `gcloud` does it:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID --member=serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com --role='roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator'
```

and now I get valid signed URLs back.

Comment: Your post does not show what you did in the console. You probably added the IAM role to the service account's IAM policy instead of the project's. Your answer modifies the project's IAM policy binding.

Comment: Indeed -- one of the reasons I don't like the console is it's hard to document what you're doing. I expect you're right that whatever I did there ended up being the wrong thing. The IAM setup is pretty complex -- I knew a lot about it at one time but the knowledge leaves my brain pretty fast.

Comment: This weirdly was the only way it solved for me. I had the same problem, console just doesn't works. I even thought i was doing something wrong lol It might be some kind of bug.